# How to create a new “Input Validation for Store Owner” option for attribute?

Tags: attributes, validation

I need to create a bunch of new attributes from my module, and I would like to define custom validation rules for each of the attribute. How can I do it?

edit: Your answers about magento validation in models are Ok - thanks, however I probably didn't emphasize it enough my question is How can I create a new “Input Validation for Store Owner” (this setting is in the attribute configuration panel)

Answer (score 1):

This article may be a good starting point: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-custom-model-with-custom-validation-rules/

Answer (score 1):

You should create custom backend model(s) for your attributes. Here good example of custom attribute model http://code.google.com/p/mangentovies/source/browse/trunk/app/code/local/Mage/Vatcustomer/Model/Entity/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Vatnumber.php